# CoreCompile is skipped. I want it to be happened

Tags: c#, msbuild

My scenario is, I have a set of c# files source controlled. I download it, I build the solution file using this command in command-line.

`"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" MyProj.sln /property:Platform=x64`

But when I do this, CoreCompile is skipped saying "Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files." The problem is, it produces a dll which does not include many changes in .cs file.

When I do a small change (ex. putting a log) in .cs file, then it is built fine and the produced dll contained all changes.

However, the 32 bit version is built without skipping CoreCompile the first time itself. (the same command but with `/property:Platform=x86`)

I could not understand this behavior. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the version of msbuild included in the .net framework (version 4.*) is quite old. New versions are part of VS and also available using the Build Tools installer

Answer (score 2):

MSBuild is able to [build incrementally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/incremental-builds). It does so by detecting changes to input files between and missing output files for each target. If you update a repository and no change to `.cs` files are made, it should skip `CoreCompile`. You can look up the inputs and outputs for a recent roslyn version [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/400238e370ef760e178dd7a9db790e5feae7f3fb/src/Compilers/Core/MSBuildTask/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets#L17-L37).

You can force a clean build using `/t:Rebuild` (which is the same as `"/t:Clean;Build"`).

Also note that changing parameters passed in via `/p:name=value` usually don't affect the build. Incremental build logic is based on file changes, not on values. If a parameter that affects the output directory changes, then the output is considered missing. if only a parameter changes that has affects some compile setting, it may trigger a target on incremental build. These kind of settings are usually set in the project, which would cause a change to `$(MSBuildAllProjects)` which is usually an input to incremental targets.

E.g. in .NET Core [there was a problem](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/967) when setting `/p:Version=1.2.3` or `/p:VersionSuffix=beta1` which did not affect incremental builds.

Comment: Hey martin, `/t:Rebuild` works in my case. But, what could be the reason for the odd behavior that, 32 bit build's CoreCompile is done but the 64bit build's ?

Comment: Edited the answer: looks like `Platform` doesn't necessarily change the inputs of CoreCompile when passing it via command line. I linked a GitHub issue of an incremental build issue I worked on recently which suffered from similar issues (command line parameters not affecting builds), it may be an interesting read.

Comment: Thanks Martin. But, I am still not able to understand the behavior. `/t:Rebuild` or `/t:Clean;Build` works from the second time. When the very first time executed, it just says "skipping CoreCompil.......". But no changes were made between these two execution. Is there any way to make it happen in the first time itself ? Since our build process execute this command one time only.

Comment: so CoreCompile is skipped from a "fresh clone" of the repository even if used with `/t:Rebuild`? That doesn't sound right. You'd need to post the csproj file somewhere to get a repo. also do use the msbuild versions included in VS / Build tools. Version "4" is ~7 years old.

Comment: Hey bro.. The problem is solved. I was having the output bin folder also (\bin\debug\x64\*) into the repository. So, the newer files were not built during the build process (using msbuild). When I removed the folder from the repository, started working. Thanks for you information Martin. :)